# Async operations on redis message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, redis

I am trying to update a mongoose model when a redis client publishes a message.

This is what i'm doing for it to work

```
redisClient.on('message', (channel, message) => {
let data=  JSON.parse(message);

console.log(message);

let user_id = data.user_id;
let story_id = data.story_id;

let ratingDetails = data.ratingDetails;

User.findById(user_id, (err, user) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    user.rating += (ratingDetails.polarity * ratingDetails.rating);

    console.log(ratingDetails);

    console.log(user.rating);

    user.save((err) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);
    });
});

Story.findById(story_id, (err, story) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    story.totalRating += (ratingDetails.polarity * ratingDetails.rating);

    story.save((err) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);
    });
});
```

});

**console.log(message)** is showing the passed message but it isn't performing any mongoose operations. The models aren't being updated.

I'm using redis for the first time. Is this a good approach or are there other alternative for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution, I was doing all redis stuff in another node process, so the Mongo connection wasn't available in the redis process.

I just created another connection in redis process and solved the problem.